# c# file server client receiving file before server finishes sending

Tags: c#, file, sockets, client, socketserver

im having some trouble with a file server that i made in c#. The problem is that when i run both the server and the client in my computer, they work fine, but when i use the client on another computer, the client receives the file before the server can finish sending it. any input would help. thanks.

server:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
namespace PortalServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static Stream stream01;
        static long length;
        static int int04;
        static int int03;
        static int int02;
        static int int01;
        static TcpListener tcp01;
        static TcpClient tcp02;
        static FileStream s01;
        static byte[] data01;
        static byte[] data02;
        static byte[] data03;
        static byte[] data04;
        static byte[] data05;
        static string str01;
        static string str02;
        static IPEndPoint ipe01;
        static string port01;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
            label1:
                try
                {
                    string version = "V:1.1.1";
                    Console.Title = (" Portal Server " + version);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("         PORTAL SERVER " + version);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                    data02 = new byte[1];
                    Console.Write(" Enter port for connecting clients : ");
                    port01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write(" Enter path of file to send : ");
                    str01 = Console.ReadLine();
                    ipe01 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(port01));
                    tcp01 = new TcpListener(ipe01);
                    Console.Write(" Enter server message : ");
                    str02 = Console.ReadLine();
                    s01 = File.OpenRead(@str01);
                    length = s01.Length;
                    Console.WriteLine(" Computing optimum byte size...");
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 30000; i++)
                    {
                        if (s01.Length % i == 0) { int02 = i; }
                    }
                    if (length < 65000) { int02 = Convert.ToInt32(length); }
                    Console.WriteLine(" Done." + " Optimum byte size is " + int02);
                    tcp01.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Server started. Waiting for clients...");
                    tcp02 = tcp01.AcceptTcpClient();
                    stream01 = tcp02.GetStream();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Client " + tcp02.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected.");
                    data05 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str02);
                    stream01.Write(data05, 0, data05.Length);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    data04 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str01);
                    stream01.Write(data04, 0, data04.Length);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    data03 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(length.ToString());
                    stream01.Write(data03, 0, data03.Length);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Waiting for response...");
                    stream01.Read((new byte[1]), 0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Received response...");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Sending file to " + tcp02.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "...");
                    int03 = (Convert.ToInt32(length) / int02);
                    int04 = 0;
                    for (int01 = 0; int01 <= int03; int01++)
                    {

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                        data01 = new byte[int02];
                        s01.Read(data01, 0, data01.Length);
                        stream01.Write(data01, 0, data01.Length);
                        stream01.Read(new byte[1], 0, 1);
                    }
                    s01.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(" All data sent.");
                    Console.WriteLine(" Waiting for terminate message...");
                    stream01.Read((new byte[1]), 0, 1);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Received terminate message.");
                    tcp02.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Stopping client and server.");
                    tcp01.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine(" Done. Restarting.");

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e.Message.ToString());
                    if (!(tcp02 == null)) { tcp02.Close(); }
                    if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Stop(); goto label1; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

client :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
namespace PortalClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static Stream stream01;
        static byte[] data03;
        static int int04;
        static int int03;
        static int int02;
        static string str01;
        static int length;
        static IPEndPoint ipe01;
        static TcpClient tcp01;
        static FileStream s01;
        static string ip01;
        static string port01;
        static string path01;
        static byte[] data01;
        static byte[] data02;
        static byte[] data04;
        static byte[] data05;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (true)
            {
            label1:
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string version = "V:1.1.1";
                        Console.Title = (" Portal Client " + version);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("         PORTAL CLIENT " + version);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                        data01 = new byte[20];
                        data03 = new byte[100];
                        data04 = new byte[100];
                        Console.Write(" Enter IPv4 address of server : ");
                        ip01 = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write(" Enter port to connect on : ");
                        port01 = Console.ReadLine();
                        ipe01 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip01), Convert.ToInt32(port01));
                        tcp01 = new TcpClient();
                        Console.WriteLine(" Connecting...");
                        tcp01.Connect(ipe01);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Done.");
                        stream01 = tcp01.GetStream();
                        Console.WriteLine(" Stream aquired.");
                        stream01.Read(data04, 0, data04.Length);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Server message : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data04));
                        stream01.Read(data03, 0, data03.Length);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Console.WriteLine(" File on server : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data03));
                        stream01.Read(data01, 0, data01.Length);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        str01 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data01);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine(" file size : " + str01);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write(" Enter the number you see above : ");
                        length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine(" Computing optimum byte size...");
                        for (int i = 1; i <= 30000; i++)
                        {
                            if (length % i == 0) { int02 = i; }
                        }
                        if (length < 65000) { int02 = Convert.ToInt32(length); }
                        Console.WriteLine(" Done. Optimum byte size is " + int02);
                        int03 = (length / int02);
                        int04 = 0;
                        Console.Write(" Save file as : ");
                        path01 = Console.ReadLine();
                        s01 = File.OpenWrite(@path01);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Receiving file from " + tcp01.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + "...");
                        stream01.Write((new byte[1]), 0, 1);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        for (int i = 0; i <= int03; i++)
                        {

                            data02 = new byte[65000];
                            data05 = new byte[int02]; 
                            stream01.Read(data02, 0, data02.Length);
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(data02, 0, data05, 0, int02);
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
                            s01.Write(data05, 0, data05.Length);
                            stream01.Write(new byte[1], 0, 1);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(" Received all data.");
                        Console.WriteLine(" Press enter to disconnect...");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        stream01.Write((new byte[1]), 0, 1);
                        Console.WriteLine(" Disconnecting...");
                        s01.Close();
                        stream01.Close();
                        tcp01.Close();
                        Console.WriteLine(" Done.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" Error! : " + e.Message.ToString()); if (!(tcp01 == null)) { tcp01.Close(); } if (!(s01 == null)) { s01.Close(); goto label1; }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might seem a little odd, but have you considered simply using an established protocol like FTP to achieve this?  Is there any reason you are re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: writing sn ftp server in c# is no easy task. by the way i was hoping no more questions like this would pop up. im doing this way because i want to. fair enough?

Comment: You wouldn't need to write your own FTP Server in C#.  You would simply use one of the many free products available.  Since you're writing in C#, I assuming you're developing on Windows.  Therefore, If you have a Windows machine acting as your server, you can install IIS and FTP Server in Windows and simply share the file that way.  If you'd like, I have code which connects to an FTP server, and saves the file locally using C#.  If you want to re-invent the wheel though, hopefully somebody else here can assist you.

Comment: Isn't what you're experiencing to be expected ? You open a socket connection between two computers; you then start sending data and the other side starts receiving. I would expect that the receiving end will be reading the socket stream before the sending has finished if the file is of sufficient size (ie not too small).

Comment: If you had read the code i beleive you would see what i was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on Stream.Read()

The last parameter you pass is the 'maximum' number of bytes to read, it doesnt guarantee it'll read all the bytes you ask for in a single call.

The Read method returns the actual number of bytes read, and from that you can decide if you need to call it again to get any more if you were expecting more. You'll also need to manage the reading of the subsequent bytes to the correct place in the array you pass, etc.